# Sort objects by property value

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following object key structure:

```
var obj = {
  "1": {name: "test", groups: [...]},
  "2": {name: "best", groups: [...]},
  "4": {name: "pick", groups: [...]}  
}
```

I would like to sort 'obj' by property 'name' value.

Desired outcome:

```
var obj = {
  "2": {name: "best", groups: [...]},
  "4": {name: "pick", groups: [...]},
  "1": {name: "test", groups: [...]}  
}
```

What I have tried so far using lodash libraries toPairs(), fromPairs() and sortBy() methods:

```
var toPairs = _.toPairs(obj);

var test = _.sortBy(toPairs, [function (o) {                
                 return o[1].name;
            }]);
```

'test' variable contains an array where the values are sorted as it is desired:

'test' output:

```
[["2", {name: "best", ...}], ["4", {name: "pick", ...}],["1", {name: "test"}]]
```

But when I am using fromPairs() method to convert the array back to object the result object is not sorted:

```
var sortedObj = _.fromPairs(test);
```

'SortedObj' output:

```
{
  "1": {name: "test", groups: [...]},
  "2": {name: "best", groups: [...]},
  "4": {name: "pick", groups: [...]}  
}
```

Comment: You can't sort objects, they are like dictionaries